# Safari In-App Browser supports Cookies?

Tags: safari

I have an iOS app, which is linking to Amazon products within the in-app Safari browser. Users stay in the app. Do you know whether the in-app-browser supports cookies? And do these cookies stay, when users go to the mobile amazon website in preinstalled safari app? And is there a difference between new and old safari in app browser?

Looking forward, thanks!!!
Philipp